# Average of a summary metric prometheus

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana

I have a summary metric called `rider_filler_processing_message_time`.

It gives me percentiles of the latency.

How can I get the average latency including all the percentiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using this query:
`sum(rate(a_sum[interval])) / sum(rate(a_count[interval]))`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what means
but i think this query can solve your problem

`sum_over_time(your_metric[5m]) /sum(count_over_time(your_metric[5m]))`

I hope to solve your question